# electron-forge app starts up with blank screen

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-forge

Under OS X, Node 10.7.0.

I created the electron-forge app with:

```
electron-forge init app-name --template=react
```

Some version info:

```
"electron-forge": "^5.2.2",
"react": "^16.4.2",
"electron-prebuilt-compile": "2.0.7",
"electron-compile": "^6.4.3",
```

I can provide other version info if necessary.

The only things I changed from the stock electron-forge build was the React version (I'm using material-ui 1.5.1). It works fine under `electron-forge start`, it's only the built one that fails.

My initial assumption was that the `text/jsx` script in the default `index.html` wasn't working; I replaced it with the transpiled code, same issue. My next assumption is the Node version, which would be a bit of a let-down if that turns out to be it.

A naive upgrade to `electron-forge#master` did not resolve the issue.

I'm not sure how to debug the packaged application (things like `--verbose --debug` did nothing) and the dev tools don't show up even if I remove the comment around the `installExtension` or hit the normal dev console keys.

I don't know enough to know what other information might be required; just let me know.

Comment: in index.js keep `mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();` out of the `if(isDevMode)` section, I guess there is problem with ES6 somewhere like `unexpected token 'import'`

Comment: @baskax That was my assumption too-I removed the conditional but same result.